# Writing a 'bq load' statement but continue to get "Syntax error: Expected end of input but got identifier 'bq'"

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm following this documentation on how to use the 'bq load' command to load data into BigQuery from a CSV in Google Cloud: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv

However, I keep getting the same error: "Syntax error: Expected end of input but got identifier "bq" at [12:1]"

This is the very first part of my code, why is it expecting to get an end of input identifier? It's the beginning of my code. I have researched all over the internet and cannot find somebody with a similar issue.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Here's the code:

```
bq load \
    --source_format=CSV \
    cpo_metrics.12mo_hc \
    gs://unity-ai-people-prd-test/12mo_hc.csv \
    --autodetect=TRUE;


Here's what it looks like when I'm trying to run in the BQ console:

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIDut.png
```

Comment: The --autodetect option doesn't need "=TRUE" since specifying it is good enough.

Also, what is the rest of the code because this is implying that there was something before this?

Comment: Are you running this command in the SQL query editor?  This code is meant to run in the console.

Comment: I am running this in the BigQuery console, yes. Also, there is no other code before this line of code (except for comments). I have updated my original post and included a link to a screenshot of what I'm seeing in my console, including the error message. Thanks agains for your help!

Comment: Ah yeah, the image helps a lot -- @rtenha is right, this code are console commands, not bigquery SQL.  You can execute in your cloud shell here: https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?cloudshell=true. Learn more here: https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs